# How to store binary numbers in C

Tags: c

I need to take an IP address and get its subnet. Currently I am thinking of converting the IP to a binary number, then use a bit-wise AND operator on it and the binary number representing the subnet mask. However I am unsure how to store these binary numbers. They aren't int, char, long, etc. So what kind of variable stores binary numbers?

Comment: `They aren't ints, chars, longs, etc...`: Wrong.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "binary number", there are just numbers. (Which you can choose to print out in binary)

Comment: Also "They aren't ints,chars,longs, etc" - what makes you think that?

Comment: An IPv4 can fit in 32 bits (unsigned int on most computers). An IPv6 would need 16 bytes, i.e. 16 unsigned chars.

Comment: I see, my bad, I was confused, I figured int a = 1100 is one thousand one hundred not 12. It just dawned upon me that 1100 is one thousand one hundred in most situations, but im guessing using a bit-wise operator on 'a' would result in c considering each digit as a bit

Comment: think of it this way. numbers are stored as binary regardless of wether you use the decimal version of that number in the source code. so, if a = 12 (binary 1100) and then i say a = a | 2 (or with binary 10), the result is 14 (binary 1110)

Comment: Your question is not really that bad, (we get lots of n00b questions here, the n00bness of a question does not make it good or bad,) but I suppose your question has been downvoted because instead of asking what you need to do in order to accomplish your goal you listed some false preconceptions that you had, and people disliked these false preconceptions. Don't let that ruin your day, it is not a big deal, we all have to learn somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert the IP to a *number*.  A suitable data type for this is a 32-bit number.  If you are using a 32-bit compiler, then an `int` will do just fine.

Then, you just need to `AND` that `int` with your subnet mask.  Forget about converting to binary.  Computers store all information, including numbers, in *bits*, so all numbers are already represented in binary inside the computer.

So, what you see as "12" (in decimal) in your source code is internally represented as "1100" (in binary) and it is ready to be `AND`ed with whatever you want to `AND` it with.

Answer (score 2):

All ints are actually stored as binary. You can simply store 8bit integer values in an unsigned char variable and use bitwise operations on those.

Comment: Please show what you mean using an example. That will increase the value of your answer and make it more complete and meaningful.